# Question on finding V of capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I know this is an easy question but for some reason I'm not getting the correct answer.
The question is:

The current through a \$100 \mu\text{F}\$ capacitor is $$i(t)=50\sin(120\pi t)\text{ mA}$$

Calculate the voltage across it at \$t=1\text{ ms}\$ and \$t=5\text{ ms}\$.

Assume \$v(0)=0\$.

So, $$v(t)=1/C \int i(t)dt + V(t_0)$$

Isn't the integral of \$i(t)\$ in this case equal to \$50(-\cos120\pi \times t/120\pi)\$?

I've been stuck on this question for like 20 minutes. I could use some help. Thanks.

The answers are \$V(1\text{ ms})= -93.14\text{ V}\$ and \$V(5\text{ ms})= -1.74\text{ V}\$

Comment: Where is your capacitor voltage equation \$ i(t) = C\frac{dv}{dt}\$ ? Have you read [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor)? All the equations are there.

Comment: I don't think you can assume v(0) = 0 because that wrecks things initially.

Comment: Set your calculator mode to Radian not Degree.

Answer (score 0):

I think its correct (or close). Your integral is not correct, it needs to be bounded. I get $$(1/C)\times (-5/12\pi) \times (\cos120\pi \times t)$$ bounded from \$t=1\text{ ms}\$ to \$t=0\$. At 1ms I get 92.84mV, pretty close.

Comment: Did you do conversion from mA to A? or mV to V?

Comment: Yes. C is in micro farads, which gives us a factor of 10,000 to multiply the answer by

Comment: Oops, I see what you mean. I think your right, should be mV there. Been 8 months since I've looked at anything like this

Comment: I have not seen a lot of capacitor this size rated at ~100V.

Comment: Ha. That's also a good point. Although many of the textbook questions I have worked through do not make any real life sense.

Comment: True. And they assume ideal characteristics which is never the case since you always have parasitics

Comment: Energy storage oil-capacitor, the size of a big wastebasket, 100uF.   Good for plasma-pinch experiments, can-crushers, quarter-shrinkers.

Comment: That's because they oftenn really are math problems, not engineering problems.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the equation that you will need to resolve this problem:

$$\int_{-\infty}^t idt = \int_{-\infty}^t C\frac{dv}{dt}dt$$

$$v = \frac{1}{C}\int_{-\infty}^t idt = \frac{1}{C}\int_{0}^t idt + v(0)$$

$$\int\sin axdx = -\frac{1}{a}\cos ax$$

I have performed the integral to calculate the voltage function in this case.  The resulting integral is indeed \$-50/377(\cos377t)\text{ mV}\$.  We are still in millivolts here so you will have to do conversion later on to volts.  By solving the definite integral with 1ms at the top and 0ms at the bottom, I get a result of 93.14mV.  Therefore, the answer should be 0.09314V for the voltage across the capacitor at 1ms.

For 5ms, you simply repeat the same definite integral calculation with 5ms at the top and 0ms at the bottom of the integral.  The result should be 1736.15mV which is equal to 1.736V.

So my guess is that the answer given are wrong or you have made a typo.